# Can someone provide some clarity on Get-PnPWorkflowDefinition?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I'm a little confused on this and haven't found much helpful info in hours of googling.

I've got a 2010 workflow in SPO. I've opened it in SPD and can see there are, in fact, several steps to the wf. However, it appears the wf has never been run and has zero items in the wf history list. Also, the associated wf history list looks like it's never had any items added to it. But, that's aside from my issue.

When I try to get the wf definition via PnP, it comes up empty with zero properties.

My code is as follows-

```
# Add paths do SharePoint SDK dll's
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.dll"

# Set vars for accessing SPO
$AppId = "{myappid}"
$Tenant = "{mycompany}.onmicrosoft.com"
$Thumbprint = "{mythumbprint}"

# SPO Admin Svc
$spoSvc = "https://{mycompany}-admin.{mycompany}.com"
Connect-SPOService ($spoSvc) -ClientId $AppId -Tenant:$Tenant -Thumbprint:$Thumbprint

# Site collection and site urls for testing
$sitecolurl = "{mysitecollectionurl}"
$siteurl = "{mysitecollectionurl}/{subweb}"
$wfname = "{myWFname}"

#Connect to site with MFA
Connect-PnPOnline -url:$siteurl -UseWebLogin

# Connect to site 
$ctx = Get-PnPContext

$wfm = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager -ArgumentList $ctx, $ctx.Web

# Get a reference to the Workflow Deployment Service
$wfDeploymentService = $wfm.GetWorkflowDeploymentService()
# Load the Workflow from it's definition
$wfDefinition1 = Get-PnPWorkflowDefinition -Name $wfname
```

But $wfDefinition1 is empty. Which means the next line...

```
$wfDefinition = $wfDeploymentService.GetDefinition($wfDefinition1.Id)
```

Throws the error: Cannot convert argument "definitionId", with value: "", for "GetDefinition" to type "System.Guid"

Also, I've run the Modernization Scanner and the WF Definition ID is "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" (It's actually that value for a lot of identified workflows).

Is a definition ID like this an indication that there's something wrong with the wf or that I'm doing something wrong here?

My ultimate goal is to iterate over each found wf in the tenant, find what wfhistory list it's using, and check that wfhistory list for the wf's items and create a report based on that data.

Many thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this article:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53763.sharepoint-online-get-all-workflows-from-tenant-using-powershell-csom-and-pnp.aspx

You can not use the method of importing the file and the log method in this code

Code:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -DisableNameChecking  
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies  
 #Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
 #Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"  
 cls  
 $fileName = "Tenant_workflow_Report" #'yyyyMMddhhmm   yyyyMMdd  
 $enddate = (Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMddhhmmss")  
 #$filename =  $enddate + '_VMReport.doc'    
 $logFileName = $fileName +"_"+ $enddate+"_Log.txt"  
 $invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value    
 $directoryPath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path  
  
   $directoryPathForLog=$directoryPath+"\"+"LogFiles"  
   if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForLog))    
 {    
 New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForLog  
 #Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red  
 }  
  
#$logPath = $directoryPath + "\" + $logFileName  
$logPath = $directoryPathForLog + "\" + $logFileName  
$isLogFileCreated = $False  
  
#DLL location    
$directoryPathForDLL=$directoryPath+"\"+"Dependency Files"  
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForDLL))    
 {    
 New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForDLL  
 #Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red  
 }  
  
#DLL location  
  
$clientDLL=$directoryPathForDLL+"\"+"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
$clientDLLRuntime=$directoryPathForDLL+"\"+"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
  
Add-Type -Path $clientDLL  
Add-Type -Path $clientDLLRuntime    
  
#File Download location    
$directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation=$directoryPath+"\"+"Download Workflow Details"  
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation))    
 {    
 New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation  
 #Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red  
 }  
  
#File Download location    
  
function Write-Log([string]$logMsg)    
{  
 if(!$isLogFileCreated){  
 Write-Host "Creating Log File..."  
 if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPath))    
 {    
 Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red  
 }  
 else  
 {  
 $script:isLogFileCreated = $True  
 Write-Host "Log File ($logFileName) Created..."  
 [string]$logMessage = [System.String]::Format("[$(Get-Date)] - {0}", $logMsg)  
 Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value $logMessage  
 }  
 }  
 else  
 {  
 [string]$logMessage = [System.String]::Format("[$(Get-Date)] - {0}", $logMsg)  
 Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value $logMessage  
 }  
}  
#Object array to hold workflow details.    
$WorkflowDetailsForSPOSite=@()    
#The below function will read all workflows from a site and return the array output.    
Function Get-WorkflowAssociationsDeatilsForEachSiteInTenant()  
{  
 param  
 (  
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SPOSiteURL,    
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $UserName,  
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $Password  
 )  
 Try  
 {  
 $securePassword= $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force    
 #Setup the Context  
 $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SPOSiteURL)  
 $context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $securePassword)    
    
 $web = $context.Web  
 $context.Load($web)  
 $context.Load($web.Webs)  
    
 $context.executeQuery()    
 #Check if any subsite is available on the site.    
 if ($web.Webs.Count -ne 0)  
 {  
 foreach ($subweb in $web.Webs)  
 {    
 Get-WorkflowAssociationsDeatilsForEachSiteInTenant -SPOSiteURL $subweb.url -UserName $userName -Password $password  
 }  
 }  
  
 #Loading all lists for the particular site.  
 $context.Load($web.Lists)  
 $context.ExecuteQuery()  
    
 foreach($list in $web.Lists)  
   {  
 $context.Load($list.WorkflowAssociations)  
 $context.ExecuteQuery()  
    
 foreach($wfAssociation in $list.WorkflowAssociations)  
   {  
 if($wfAssociation.name -notlike "*Previous Version*")  
 {  
 $row=new-object PSObject  
 add-Member -inputObject $row -memberType NoteProperty -name "Site Title" -Value $web.Title  
 add-Member -inputObject $row -memberType NoteProperty -name "Site URL" -Value $web.Url  
 add-Member -inputObject $row -memberType NoteProperty -name "List Title" -Value $list.Title  
 add-Member -inputObject $row -memberType NoteProperty -name "Workflow Name" -Value $wfAssociation.Name  
 add-Member -inputObject $row -memberType NoteProperty -name "Workflow Type" -Value "SharePoint List"  
 $WorkflowDetailsForSPOSite+=$row  
 }  
 }  
 }  
 return $WorkflowDetailsForSPOSite  
  
  
 }  
 catch  
 {  
 write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red  
 $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message +"in exporting workflow details!:"  
 Write-Host $ErrorMessage -BackgroundColor Red  
 Write-Log $ErrorMessage  
  
 }  
}  
  
#Parameters  
#$siteURL="https://globalsharepoint2019.sharepoint.com/sites/ModernTeamSiteTestByPnP Jump "  
$adminUrl = "https://globalsharepoint2019-admin.sharepoint.com/ Jump "  
$downloadLocation=$directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation +"\"+ "SPOTenantWorkflowReport.csv"  
$userName = "YourSPOUserName"  
$password = "YourSPOPassWord"  
$securePassword= $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force  
  
#Parameters ends here.  
  
$SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force  
$Credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $SecurePassword  
#Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -DisableNameChecking  
#Retrieve all site collection infos  
#Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminUrl -Credential $Credentials  
#$sites = Get-SPOSite  
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $adminUrl -Credentials $Credentials  
$allTenantSites=Get-PnPTenantSite  
#Get-WorkflowAssociationsDeatilsForEachSiteInTenant -SPOSiteURL $siteURL -UserName $userName -Password $password | Export-Csv $downloadLocation  
if($allTenantSites.Count -gt 0)  
{  
 $finalWorkflowReport =foreach($oneSite in $allTenantSites)  
 {  
 Get-WorkflowAssociationsDeatilsForEachSiteInTenant -SPOSiteURL $oneSite.URL -UserName $userName -Password $password  
 }  
 $finalWorkflowReport | Export-Csv $downloadLocation -NoTypeInformation  
 }  
Write-host "All workflows have been exported Successfully from the SharePoint Online Tenant." -BackgroundColor Green
```

Comment: I do appreciate the script but it doesn't help with my issue. I can already get the workflows on the tenant. I'm trying to get the wf history list associated with each wf so I can assess whether the wf is in use or not.